# Where to start with derivative of matrix function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I know about derivatives of easy functions like $\frac{dx^2}{dx}=2x$ and such, but now that I'm dealing with matrices, I am somewhat at a loss.

Given a matrix function $f(\mathbf{X})$

$$f(\mathbf{X}) =log(y' \cdot exp(\mathbf{U X}z))$$

- where $y'$ is an m-element row vector
- $\mathbf{U}$ is an $m\times (m-1)$ , static matrix
- $\mathbf{X}$ is an $n\times (m-1)$ matrix
- $z$ is an (n+1)-element row vector

I am struggling to find the derivative 
$\frac{df}{d\mathbf{X}} $ and not sure where I should even start.

I wanted to start with the term inside the exp(). While looking around, I found  [this](http://www.uni-regensburg.de/wirtschaftswissenschaften/vwl-tschernig/medien/mitarbeiter/rameseder/matrix_derivatives.pdf) document that states on the second page $\frac{d\mathbf{AXB}}{d\mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{B}^T \bigotimes \mathbf{A}$ , which I wanted to apply, but there $\mathbf{B}$ is a matrix and not a vector.

Can someone show me how to tackle such a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define some additional variables and their differentials 
$$\eqalign{
w &= UXz &\implies dw = U\,dX\,z \cr
e &= \exp(w) &\implies de = e\odot dw \cr
\beta &= y^Te = y:e &\implies d\beta = y:de \cr
f &= \log(\beta) &\implies df = d\beta/\beta \cr
}$$
where $(\odot)$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product

and (:) denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. $\,A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$

Successively substitute into that last differential, until we get an expression in terms of $dX$ 
$$\eqalign{
df &= \beta^{-1}d\beta \cr
   &= \beta^{-1}y:de \cr
   &= \beta^{-1}y:e\odot dw \cr
   &= \beta^{-1}y\odot e:dw \cr
   &= \beta^{-1}y\odot e:U\,dX\,z \cr
   &= \beta^{-1}U^T(y\odot e)z^T:dX \cr
   &= \beta^{-1}U^TYez^T:dX \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= \frac{U^TY\exp(UXz)z^T}{y^T\exp(UXz)} \cr
}$$
where $Y={\rm Diag}(y)$ was used to eliminate the Hadamard product.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!